# How do I get the "bundle install" command to only look at the current version of "ruby" (which I chose)?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, linux-mint

I installed `Ruby (v2.6.3)` and `Rails (v5.2.3)`.

Even completed a training project on this framework.
Then he took up a working project and first of all executed the command `bundle install`.
All modules were delivered normally, except one "sassc-2.0.1"

Installation fails with this error:

> sassc-2.0.1 requires ruby version >= 2.3.3, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 2.3.1p112

That is, I chose one version, and in fact uses a different version.
I can't understand the reason for this.

But I didn't give up the first time.
I tried to check the ruby version in different ways:

(1) Get ruby version

```
$> ruby -v
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
```

(2) Get path to bin for ruby

```
$> which ruby
/home/vdenisov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby
```

(3) Get path to bin for bundle

```
$> which bundle
/home/vdenisov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/bundle
```

All these commands give out that the current version of ruby is 2.6.3

However, my friend advised me to do one more check

(4) WTF ???

```
$> /usr/bin/ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

P.S.: before that I programmed in nodejs and there is a version Manager "nvm" - when you run the command "nvm use a.b.c" in the system, always use the nodejs version of "a.b.c" (the same I expected from the "rvm").

Comment: Are you using any version manager? Such as rvm or rbenv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/bin/ruby -v` gives you the version of ruby installed in your operating system.

It seems that you already run `rvm use --default 2.6.3` because your `ruby` points to `rvm` location.

Ruby environment manager `RVM` supports configuration inside following files: `.rvmrc`, `.versions.conf`, `.ruby-version`, `Gemfile`. More here: https://rvm.io/workflow/projects

Check these files, it's good practice to set ruby version inside `.ruby-version` or `Gemfile`.

Comment: Also recommend adding a `.ruby-gemset` file to keep your gems separate for each project as a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

`bundler` gem orients on Ruby version, which locked in `Gemfile.lock`. Just change Ruby version in `Gemfile` (not .lock). Try `2.3.3` at first. Maybe you need to install it with `rvm` or `rbenv`.